# How to change the name of a Firebase parent node to enable rules with them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-security

I am creating a Firebase database and i want to add rules to my data but i cannot figure out the right way to access my data in the 'rules' section of Firebase.  When i set up my default database, the parent nodes defaulted to random letters and numbers like in this data shown below

[image]

How can i change the name of these nodes to allow me to access them in the 'rules' section of Firebase or how can I access them with the configuration I have currently?

I have tried to access them like this:[image]

and i have also tried nesting another reference inside "rules{}" like "message{}" and "#messageId{}" but none of them have been able to read the data.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please in any future question don't use images of text. Instead: extract the text from the source and paste it. It both helps SEO and prevents me from having to manually type the text from your question into my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To a apply rules to every child under a specific node, you use a so-called *$ variable*.

So in your case:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "$messageid": {
            ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 300000)",
            ".write": true
        }
    }
}
```

So the rules under `$messageid` above apply to every message.

For more information, see the [Firebase documentation on using $ variables](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-dollar-variables).

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.  i have tried nesting a $messageid reference in my rules like you have shown above and I have even changed both ".read" and ".write" to true, keeping the "rules" and the "$messageid" references and when i run a simulator it is still telling me I have no read rule.  I believe it is because the nodes that contain children aren't named "messageid" is that correct? Or is "messageid" a universal reference to parent nodes.

Comment: Nope. The name of the $ variable makes no difference, it's just a variable name. But it must start with a $ to be applied to all children.

Comment: Also note that you cannot use rules to **filter** data. An entire read/write operation either succeeds or fails: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter